# What is the purpose of putting a data type in brackets before a calculation?

Tags: data-type

sorry for the nooby question but I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere, probably because I'm unsure what to search for with this problem!

I'm just wondering what the reason is for including a data type in brackets before a calculation takes place? In the code below, all the variables have already been declared at the top of the program, so I'm unsure what the reason / effect of including the (float) has. acc_y and angle_pitch_acc have been declared as floats and acc_total_vector has been declared as long

```
angle_pitch_acc = asin((float)acc_y/acc_total_vector)* 57.296;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called *casting*. It changes the data type temporarily. In this instance it's being used to change an integer type into a floating point type, which means that the whole calculation is done using floating point mathematics. However `acc_y` is supposedly already a float, but maybe it wasn't at the time the author wrote that line. Maybe things, as they often do in a program, evolved. Only the author knows.

Comment: The OP wrote, that `acc_y` is declared as float. So the calculation would already be a floating point one, I think

Comment: @chrisl I stopped reading at "I wonder..."

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense.